# Does the rank-nullity theorem extends to vector spaces of infinite dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation, $T:V \rightarrow W$

The rank-nullity theorem states that $\dim(\ker(T)) +\dim(img(T)) = \dim(V)$.

However does this holds if $W$ has infinite dimension?

Comment: It's $\dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{im} T = \dim V$, the domain's dimension, not the codomain's. And it extends to infinite-dimensional $V$, using cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: It also generalizes vastly using category theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma